# Not able to convert image from url into byte array

Tags: android, arrays, image

I am new to android and I need to save image from url into db and fetch it from db. I an converting image from link into byte array but getting the following error:

> Cannot Resolve ByteArrayBuffer

**This is the code:**

```
 private byte[] getLogoImage(String url){
    try {
             URL imageUrl = new URL(url);
             URLConnection ucon = imageUrl.openConnection();

             InputStream is = ucon.getInputStream();
             BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);

             ByteArrayBuffer baf = new ByteArrayBuffer(500);
             int current = 0;
             while ((current = bis.read()) != -1) {
                     baf.append((byte) current);
             }

             return baf.toByteArray();
     } catch (Exception e) {
             Log.d("ImageManager", "Error: " + e.toString());
     }
     return null;
}
```

Comment: check your  imports

Comment: Please post your error logs, thanks.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the user guidelines on how to ask a good question before posting a question (http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) Thank You

Answer (score 1):

Update your method `getLogoImage()` as below.

Use `AsyncTask` and call this method from `doInBackground()`.

**Here is the working code. Try this:**

```
private byte[] getLogoImage(String url) {

    try {

        URL imageUrl = new URL(url);
        URLConnection ucon = imageUrl.openConnection();

        InputStream is = ucon.getInputStream();

        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int read = 0;

        while ((read = is.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length)) != -1) {
            baos.write(buffer, 0, read);
        }

        baos.flush();

        return  baos.toByteArray();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d("ImageManager", "Error: " + e.toString());
    }

    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
Bitmap bm = null;
   InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
        BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);
        bm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(bis);
       byte[] imageArray = getBytes(bm);
```

and after this use below method

```
  public static byte[] getBytes(Bitmap bitmap) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, stream);
    return stream.toByteArray();
}
```

Comment: Pretty bad code to convert the received bytes to a bitmap first. Memory problems. No need to do so as you can put the received bytes directly in a byte array.  Or write them to a byte array output stream.

Comment: so can you explain me Mr greenapps how i can do that with explaination

Comment: and suppose if i want to compress my image first thn i want to get byte array how i can do that explain me that also

Answer (score 0):

Use This

```
BitmapFactory.Options options = null;
            options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            options.inSampleSize = 3;
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(url,
                    options);
            ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 50, stream);
            byte[] byte_arr = stream.toByteArray();
```

Comment: getting this error http://prntscr.com/eqpmom while I am using code as 
http://prntscr.com/eqpn24

Comment: Pretty bad code to convert the received bytes to a bitmap first. Memory problems. No need to do so as you can put the received bytes directly in a byte array. As OP is trying to do. Better help him.

Comment: Are u sure file exist inside your device.

Comment: I am getting it from server link

Comment: You need to first download the image then convert into byteArray.